# Sending POST with Python to PHP

Tags: python, php

I'm trying to send simple data from a python script on my laptop, to my own site hosted on hostgator, but I cannot get it to work.

This is my python script:

```
import requests

url = 'http://******.com/***/test.php'
query = {'site': 'test'}

res = request.post(url, query)
print(res)
```

And this is the php running on my site:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*****";
$pass = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";
?>

<?php
if($_REQUEST["site"]){
    $site = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["site"]);
    echo "Success";
    {
        //Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
        //Check connection
        if ($conn -> connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (SITE) VALUES ('$site')";

        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record added successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

The problem shouldn't be with the database connection, as I have tested this and it seems to be working.

When I run the python script on my linux machine, I get a response 406 and see no insertion in the database.

I probably just need a pair of fresh eyes.

Thanks

Comment: try to add an `else` block in php code to debug if you are getting `$_REQUEST["site"]` after post request.

Comment: My secondary problem is that I get a response 406, when using my script, so I can't view the actual response from the server

Comment: i am asking to update the php code on server itself to see if you can read the `$_REQUEST["site"]` from the client. Also if you can try to read `$_POST["site"]` in php code. maybe that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same problem as me, I solved it by adding a header to my post request like so:

```
import requests

url = 'http://******.com/***/test.php'
query = {'site': 'test'}

res = request.post(url, query, headers={"User-Agent": "Firefox/12.0"})
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is here:
res = request.post(url, query)  >> You must use requests not request
you ignored the "s" character

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).